# If two sets X and Y have different sizes, can they have the same number of subsets?

Tags: set-theory

The converse of this is definitely false, if two sets have the same size then their powersets must also be the same size. But I suspect that two sets such that |X|≠|Y|, something surrounding the Continuum Hypothesis would allow |P(X)| = |P(Y)|. Do any such sets exist, perhaps in models of ZFC + ¬CH?